# ABRecordRef not returning email or phone numbers for contacts that have them

Tags: ios, addressbook

In my app, I am attempting to provide users the ability to import users directly from contacts. I display a custom view controller which lists all of the Contacts in the address book. For contacts that don't have first name and last name, I have the cell display either the email address or phone number but both are currently nil for contacts that have at least one or the other.

I have tried each of the following to get the values:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
CFTypeRef emailProp = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

1) NSArray *email = [((NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProp)) objectAtIndex:0];

2) NSArray *emails =(__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emails);    

3) NSString *email = (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0);
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior.  Did you isolate the issue?

Comment: It seems to be that the ABRecordRef is not fully populated if you look at it during the peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson and not during the method that is called after the next controller is shown